# Why python raises the error OSError while loading a dll with ctypes?

Tags: python

I need to interface a `.dll` with python during a project.
I'm running python on `macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4` and using `Python 3.6.0 64bits`.
Here is my code :

```
import ctypes
zelib = ctypes.CDLL("as5216x64.dll")
```

This raises me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-36-d20b19e4224c>", line 1, in <module>
Clib = ffi.dlopen("as5216x64.dll")

File "/Users/Thomas/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 139, in dlopen
lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)

File "/Users/Thomas/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 769, in _make_ffi_library
backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)

File "/Users/Thomas/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 758, in _load_backend_lib
return backend.load_library(name, flags)

OSError: cannot load library as5216x64.dll: dlopen(as5216x64.dll, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
as5216x64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
/Users/Thomas/CALAIDOSCOPE/as5216x64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

I also tried using `cffi` but it raised the same error.
The `.dll` i'm trying to use is made to interface a hardware i really need to use.

Comment: Is the .dll supported for Mac? I always thought you had to use a .dylib for dynamic libraries in Mac OS.

Comment: That file is a Windows DLL. It will not work on a Apple system. It begins with 0x4D 0x5A which in little end is 0x5A4D which is the signature for a Windows PE format.